# How to overcome language learning fatigue when learning Standard Chinese?

Tags: chinese, motivation

An acquaintance of mine has been learning Standard Chinese in his spare time for a number of years. He passed the HSK3 test with a very high score and started preparing for HSK4. However, he recently noticed that he lost his motivation to continue. What's worse, he even noticed a certain aversion from learning Chinese now. So he decided to take a break for a few months to see what will happen. Are there any better ideas than this?

(Note: He doesn't need to learn Chinese for professional reasons and currently can't think of any specific learning goals that he still considers worth pursuing.)

Comment: Is this person's situation any different from a typical "loss of motivation" pattern? If not, have they considered [standard methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/3183/) of creating (semi-)artificial self-motivative reasons to continue the study?

Comment: @bytebuster In this particular case there is neither "necessity" (no specific learning goals) nor fun (there's even aversion now). So I don't think the answer you pointed to would work.

Comment: add fun: listen to songs, watching movies, chatting with friends. Especially the ability to communicate with others in their native language can be very satisfying. You don't necessarily learn, but you maintain a certain level.

Comment: I can't think of anything better to motivate your friend than a trip to China or Taiwan. Going to a country where the L2 is natively spoken is the best motivator, in my opinion.